# Is the singleton closed in this topology?

Tags: general-topology

> let $\tau=\{0_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\emptyset,\mathbb{Z}\}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ s.t $O_{n}=\{n,n+1,n+2,...\}$ is a singleton is open in this topology?

So we look at $\{n\}^{c}=\{i+1,i+2,...:i \in \mathbb{N}\}=\cup_{i\neq n}O_{n}$ this is an infinite union of open sets and therefore the complement of a singleton is open, and therefore the singleton is closed?

Comment: Please explicitly tell us what your overall space is, $\mathbb N$, $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb R$, ......? I'm guessing $\mathbb Z$, but it makes an important difference (as we're looking at the complement of singleton sets).

Comment: Added, it is $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Then your expression for $\{n\}^c$ doesn't look right.

Comment: It should be Z\{n} right

Comment: Wait, your title and question are different! Do we want to know if singletons are __closed__ or __open__?

Comment: Closed, the complement is open

Comment: Then edit your question: "....  is a singleton is __closed__ in this topology?"

Comment: It seems like negative integers are for the most part excluded from the topology, so the complement of a singleton could never be open?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is going to be "no". $\mathbb Z \backslash \{c\}$ is going to have all the negative integers but every open set (except for $\emptyset$ or $\mathbb Z$) has a smallest element.